# Order by unique column, but keep matching columns together

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to return a sorted list of entries by their date, but keep matching columns together.

For a super simplified example, the table **food** is as follows.

| id | name | group_uuid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 6d37ca | 2023-05-20 |
| 2 | Cucumber | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 3 | Orange | 6d37ca | 2023-06-14 |
| 4 | Carrot | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 5 | Walnut | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |
| 6 | Pecan | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |

Is there a way to produce a result where the Orange comes directly after Apple, but not ordering by group_uuid alphabetically? I'd want to keep the group `6d37ca` at the top since its first entry has an `id` of `1`.

If I use `SELECT * FROM food ORDER BY date ASC, type, id ASC` it'll produce the following result:

| id | name | group_uuid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 6d37ca | 2023-05-20 |
| 2 | Cucumber | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 4 | Carrot | vegetable | 2023-05-20 |
| 3 | Orange | d90ad2 | 2023-06-14 |
| 5 | Walnut | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |
| 6 | Pecan | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |

I'd ideally want the result to look like this:

| id | name | group_uuid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 6d37ca | 2023-05-20 |
| 3 | Orange | 6d37ca | 2023-06-14 |
| 2 | Cucumber | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 4 | Carrot | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 5 | Walnut | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |
| 6 | Pecan | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |

Not sure if it's possible or not, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? I have a solution with window functions, but it requires MySQL 8.0. If you aren't using MySQL 8.0, I won't bother posting the answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin Looks like my server only has `5.6.41-84.1`

Comment: No clue what the goal is here, but `order by CASE Name when 'Apple' then 0 when 'Orange' then 1 else 2, date, type, id` would give you your result. Edit actually i'm not sure about the allowed case statement syntax; you might have to use `CASE when Name LIKE 'Apple' then 0 when Name LIKE 'Orange' then 1 else 2`. (Ok checked the doc and both are OK)

Comment: OK now I think I understand your question. You could try this: `select food.* from food join (select min(id) group_min_id, group_uuid u from food group by group_uuid) t1 on group_uuid = u order by group_min_id, id`, this will first order the groups according to what member they have with the lowest id, then each group has its members ordered by id. it gave me the exact result you wanted.

Comment: @Moige Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK full answer extracted from my previous comments:

Just putting `Apple` in first position and `Orange` is second is straightforward enough. You use a `CASE WHEN` [statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to order your elements according to your arbitrary desire (`Apple` is `0`, `Orange` is `1`, everything else is `2`) then further refine the order for all other elements as needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM food
ORDER BY CASE Name WHEN 'Apple' THEN 0 WHEN 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 2, date ASC, type, id ASC
```

note that the `ASC` there are superfluous as they are the default in most cases.

However you mentioned you 'want to keep the group `6d37ca` at the top', and your desired result indicates you're actually shooting for ordered groups, with each group's position being decided by their member with the lowest `ID`. The first step is to get that lowest `ID`, which is done using the `GROUP BY` statement and the `MIN()` [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html):

```
SELECT MIN(id) group_min_id, group_uuid
FROM food
GROUP BY group_uuid
```

You then need to join this to your entire table, so each row in food "learns of" the lowest `ID` of the group they belong to:

```
SELECT *
FROM food
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) group_min_id, group_uuid
  FROM food
  GROUP BY group_uuid) T1
ON food.group_uuid = T1.group_uuid
```

`T1` here is an [ALIAS](https://sql.sh/cours/alias), that is necessary to identify the temporary table created by our sub-query. It also allows us to differenciate between the two `group_uuid` columns we have to handle during the `JOIN` (this can also be done by giving an alias to the `group_uuid` column!).

Now, you don't need to have `group_uuid` twice, and the `group_min_id`, while necessary to order your results, is not part of it either, so we'll just select `food.*` (instead of the entire `*`), and add the ordering statement. Note that we do not order over `group_uuid`, since `group_min_id` already handles this part:

```
SELECT food.*
FROM food
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) group_min_id, group_uuid
  FROM food
  GROUP BY group_uuid) T1
ON food.group_uuid = T1.group_uuid
ORDER BY group_min_id, id
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a subquery to get the group and minimum id of the group, and thus defined combine the group with the main query to then sort by the minemo id of the subquery.

Edit: after 47 tests lol [sqlfinddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a3cc8/47) \o/

Exemple:

```
CREATE TABLE food (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    group_uuid VARCHAR(6),
    date DATE
);
INSERT INTO food (id, name, group_uuid, date)
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple', '6d37ca', '2023-05-20'),
    (2, 'Cucumber', 'd90ad2', '2023-05-20'),
    (3, 'Orange', '6d37ca', '2023-06-14'),
    (4, 'Carrot', 'd90ad2', '2023-05-20'),
    (5, 'Walnut', '03a7f3', '2023-06-14'),
    (6, 'Pecan', '03a7f3', '2023-06-14');
```

And the resulting query:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, f.group_uuid, f.date
  FROM food f,
       (SELECT group_uuid, MIN(id) AS min_id
          FROM food 
         GROUP BY group_uuid) AS f2
 WHERE f.group_uuid = f2.group_uuid
 ORDER BY f2.min_id;
```

Resulting:

| id | name | group_uuid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 6d37ca | 2023-05-20 |
| 3 | Orange | 6d37ca | 2023-06-14 |
| 2 | Cucumber | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 4 | Carrot | d90ad2 | 2023-05-20 |
| 5 | Walnut | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |
| 6 | Pecan | 03a7f3 | 2023-06-14 |

Comment: Yeah, the question really obsesses over putting apple and orange in position 1 & 2, but I think he's really asking to have the items grouped up according to their group_uuid, and for the groups to be ordered according to their member with the lowest id. I'd also be surprised if mysql tolerates name and date as column names.

Comment: @Moige You articulated it way better than I did, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The table is just a simplified example, my actual data is different.

Comment: guys, it took work for this technical auxiliary procedure kkk see if that solves it?